# Calculating p-values with pnorm ( ). What makes p-values differ if data is transformed?

Tags: transform, spss, p-value, standard-error

I am comparing two alternatives for calculating p-values with R's pnorm() function.

```
xbar <- 2.1
mu <- 2
sigma <- 0.25
n = 35

# z-transformation
z <- (xbar - mu) / (sigma / sqrt(n))

# Alternative I using transformed values
pval1 <- pnorm(q = z)

# Alternative II using untransformed values
pval2 <- pnorm(q = xbar, mean = mu, sd = sigma)
```

How come the two calculated p-values are not the same? Should not they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different because you use two different estimates of the standard deviation.

In the z-transformation calculation you use `sigma / sqrt(n)` as the standard deviation, but in the untransformed calculation you use `sd = sigma`, ignoring `n`.

Comment: I've seen examples of both alternatives. How do you know which one to use?

Comment: I think you are maybe mixing and matching formulas in a bad way. If your `sigma` is a raw standard deviation of the sample - as seems to be the case judging by its size - it is the square root of the sum of the squared differences from the mean, divided by `n`. The division by `n` has already happened. It is a biased estimate, and if you want to correct it the typical way is to multiply by `sqrt(n / (n - 1))`. [See this wikipedia link for reference.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation).

Comment: So either (a) just use `sigma` as-is. This is appropriate if you used R's `sd()` function to calculate `sigma`. See the *Details* section at `?sd` where it says "this uses denominator *n - 1*", so it has already been corrected; (b) use `sigma * sqrt(n / (n - 1))`. This is appropriate if you calculated the `sigma` by hand or using some other method that doesn't do the sample correction; or (c) correct me by telling me that your `sigma` isn't a standard deviation at all and is actually `sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2))` and still needs to be divided.

Comment: It is unclear which estimate to use in this example. However, thanks for pointing out that `sd` has to be the same in both calculations for them to give the same p-value. I missed that part somehow.

Comment: I mean, it depends completely on what `sigma` is. Your question doesn't describe it at all. It's the name typically given to a standard dev, and it looks to be a reasonable size for a standard dev, so either using `sigma = 0.25` or  `sigma * sqrt(n / (n - 1)) = 0.2536498` seem reasonable - and the difference is small. But yes, as long as you are consistent your Alt 1 and Alt 2 calculations will give the same results, and that seems to be the crux of the question.

Comment: Sigma is the standard deviation in this example.

Comment: Yes, that was the crux of the question. Thanks.